# Are there any solutions to launch Hadoop MapReduce jobs using GPUs?

Tags: hadoop, gpu

I'm working on a solution that increases the performance of MapReduce jobs, especially the response time, for that I'm looking for ideas that allows me to run jobs on GPUs.
if you have proposals I am interested.

Answer (score 0):

[Hadoop YARN 3.1.x](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/UsingGpus.html) has introduced YARN on (Nvidia) GPUs

*Disclaimer* - Haven't tried it, and is still a new framework, so YMMV

Comment: what about OpenCL ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, sorry